# How can I retrieve a token from Trello API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, token, trello

I'm building an application that asks the user to authorize the application to use him Trello account.

First, I use my developer key (provided by Trello) and do a API call, like that:

```
Trello.authorize({
    type: 'popup',
    name: 'My App',
    persist: 'true', // the token will be saved on localstorage
    scope: {
        read: 'true',
        write: 'true' 
    },
    expiration: 'never',
    success: authenticationSuccess,
    error: authenticationFailure
});
```

This shows a pop up asking to user to allow (authorize).

My question is, how can I get the token in this request? This method doesn't deliver any response.

The only way I found to get the token is: send the user to...

```
https://trello.com/1/connect?key=my_developer_key&name=My+App&response_type=token&scope=read,write
```

However, the user lands on a blank page that shows:

"You have granted access to your Trello information."
"To complete the process, please give this token:"
"21265656542121245...sometoken"

I don't want the user needs to give me any token.

Can any one help me with this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `authenticationSuccess` you will be able to check the `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.trello_token
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, since `persist = true` (by default) in authOpts, I was able to access the token from the local storage using `localStorage.getItem('trello_token')` after successful authentication.